# Should I use an interface or abstract class in this scenario?

Tags: c#, oop, interface, abstract-class

I have a class with several methods, and one of them is a Save() method.  I wanted to have different implementations of Save: Save to DB, Save to File, etc. So, say this is the class:

```
MyClass 
  Add()
  Remove()
  Save()
```

Add and Remove implementations would be common to all. Only the Save would be different. In this scenario, would it be more appropriate to create an abstract class with Save as an abstract method? Or is there any benefit of using an interface?  If I were to use an interface here, I would need to duplicate the implementations of Add and Remove as well to all my classes that implement the interface, right?  It wouldn't make sense here to just have an ISave interface with just a Save method right, because all my implementing classes would still need to define Add and Remove?

Just trying to understand the usage of interfaces and abstract classes better...

Not sure if the programming language would make a difference, but I'm using C#.

Comment: You could design the program to use either quite effectively.

Comment: @Servy If I went the interfaces route, how could I do it without replicating implementations for Add and Remove?

Comment: While either would work, C# doesn't really support concrete methods on interfaces.  You can work around that with extension methods when needed, but if you have a concrete implementation in mind it's a case for an abstract class, usually.  That said, @dbc's suggestion of making the abstract class implement an interface isn't bad.

Comment: @emodendroket so the abstract class has Add and Remove implementations, and implements the Save interface, but the concrete classes would be the ones to implement and fulfill the contract to the ISave interface? Is that possible?

Comment: Have the interface specify Add, Remove, and Save.  Then in the abstract class, have it implement IMyClass, and have concrete Add and Remove methods and an abstract Save method.  Then the concrete classes can inherit AbstractMyClass and override save.

Comment: @Prabhu Create one type that adds and removes items, and then N types implementing an interface that know how to save an item.  The add/remove type will accept an instance of the interface to defer all save operations to.

Comment: @Servy So if I am understanding you correctly, The AddRemove type would just be a concrete class that takes an ISave as a parameter in its constructor? And then who ever is using AddRemove would pass a concrete instance of ISave into AddRemove's constructor?

Comment: @Servy Thanks. To wrap up my thoughts around this, what would be the benefit of doing it this way (if any) rather than just using an abstract class, in this scenario?

Comment: @Prabhu As I said right from the start, [both are just fine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272791/should-i-use-an-interface-or-abstract-class-in-this-scenario?noredirect=1#comment39381377_25272791).  My whole premise is that neither is particularly better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into the strategy design pattern : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

You can create an ISave interface and create one implementation of this interface for each save method you need to use.  FileSave, DBSave, etc etc.

You can add an ISave parameter to the constructor of MyClass and then pass the right implementation to your class depending on which save method you want to use.

Answer (score 3):

In your particular scenario, I would suggest that you use Abstract class. Per MSDN [Recommendations for Abstract Classes vs. Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scsyfw1d(v=vs.71).aspx), the recommendation applies in your scenario is:

> - If you want to provide common, implemented functionality among all implementations of your component, use an abstract class. Abstract classes allow you to partially implement your class, whereas interfaces contain no implementation for any members.

In your Abstract class you can provide functionality for "Add" and "Remove" methods and leave the implementer with requirement to override Save method using abstract(or MustOverride in VB).

See complete article for more insight.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to do both.  Since there is lots of code in common between the two derived classes, an inheritance hierarchy makes sense.  However, if you extract an interface for your classes and always access them through that, it leaves you with future flexibility if you find you need a new class with different methods for Add, Save and Remove.

Comment: How would you use both in this case? If I had a DBMyClass and FileMyClass classes, they would inherit from MyClass abstract class and then also implement an ISave interface that just has the Save method?

Comment: @Prabhu Make your abstract class implement the interface.

Answer (score 0):

It's always good to use both.

First, define an interface

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    bool Add();
    bool Remove();
    bool Save();
}
```

then define an abstract class

```
public abstract MyBaseClass : IMyInterface
{
    public bool Add() { ... }

    public bool Remove() { ... }

    public abstract bool Save();
}
```

and implement your `Save` variations in those classes that implement MyBaseClass.

Now use IMyInterface every where in your code, when you need to pass your objects.

This gives you also the ability to test things.
When 'Add' and `Remove` hit a database to add/remove things from a table, testing becomes difficult.
Then you need to setup a test database environment, point your test to that and you have to make sure that you always operate on clean tables, when running your tests.
But what if you only want to test the behaviour of a something that is calling your `Add` functions that behaves differently when `Add` returns `true` or `false`

```
public class Foo
{
    public int AddRange(MyBaseClass my, int count)
    {
        int retval = 0;
        while (count > 0)
        {
            if (my.Add())
                ++retval;
            --count;
        }
        return retval;
    }
}
```

this is now hard to test, since `Add` is bound to `MyBaseClass`. It hits the database and all that stuff that is probably to reliable during your testing. But luckely, your use interfaces. So change the signature of `AddRange`to

```
public int AddRange(IMyInterface my, int count);
```

and define your tests

```
[TestMethod]
void AddRangeReturns0ForFailedAdd()
{
    var foo = new Foo();
    Assert.AreEqual(0, foo.AddRange(new Fail(), 0));
    Assert.AreEqual(0, foo.AddRange(new Fail(), 1));
    Assert.AreEqual(0, foo.AddRange(new Fail(), 100));
}

class Fail : IMyInterface
{
     public bool Add() { return false; }

     public bool Remove() { return false; }

     public bool Save() { return false; }
}
```

Comment: In this case the interface, as you are using it, is adding zero functional value to the code itself.  This is effectively just stating an entirely unrelated practice of having everything you ever write implement it's entire public API through an interface for the sake of testing.  Depending on how the application is tested that may be appropriate, but it's unrelated to the problem described here.

Comment: @esskar I ended up going with Joel's answer (and Servy's comment), but thanks for your answer as it did help me to see the other approaches.